# How to compile on Windows with the g++ compiler and the Eigen library

Tags: c++, linux, windows, makefile, g++

I used to code on Linux and installed the Eigen library. I build my code with the g++ compiler. I want to code on Windows (8.1, 64bits) but plenty of errors (at least plenty of lines in the cmd) appear when I am compiling. Where is the problem ? Why does Windows find all these troubles ?

I created a makefile (cf. next paragraph) on Linux and everything compiled without issues. Then, I moved to Windows. I copied and paste the whole folder containing .cpp, .h, .cc files and the Eigen library, and I installed the g++ compiler through MinGW. But when I type "mingw32-make", tens of lines appear.
I use Atom as a text editor.

Makefile :

```
run: main.cc
    mingw32-g++ -Wall -g -fcheck-new -std=c++11 -I C:\Users\Utilisateur\Documents\TESTC++\eigen-eigen-b9cd8366d4e8\Eigen -o run Laplacian1D.cpp main.cc 

clean :
    rm -rf *.o *.mod *.vtk run
```

I expect not to have as many lines, and I do not know what they mean (most of them concern the Eigen library, as you can see in the screenshots).
Note that I have screenshoted the first part of the cmd, but if you want me to focus on a special part do not hesitate.

I thank you very much for your understanding and your help,
Sincerely,

Jacataa [cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2uQm.png)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you are including the wrong header file. This has nothing to do with your build setup

Comment: "Windows (8.1, 64bits) ... mingw32" - Why are you using a 32bit compiler on a 64bit OS?

Comment: `-I C:\Users` I think you should not have that space there.

Comment: Please don't link to images of error messages. Put the errors *in your question*, as *text*.

Comment: Also note that you are not enabling the compilers optimizer. You'll (by default) get a debug build. That program is going to run *slowly*.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments. I am going to answer chronologically :
- Ok, but what should I do ? I am just indicating (by taping -I C:\...) the Eigen library 's spot in the computer, right ? I think this error occurs by calling some features of this library... . And what do you mean by "build setup" ?
- On the MinGW website, it is written that it can support 32-bits or 64-bits OS. I can try to dl mingw64 however.

Comment: - Tried with "-IC:\..." and still got the same result
- Okay, sorry for the inconvenience, I did not know. I will try not to do this again in the future :) .
- Okay, so how do I enable the compilers optimizer (in order to run it faster I presume ?) ? And why is a debug build not ... effective/good/... ? 
I thank you very much for your previous and future answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find my (awful) mistake...as dumb as it is simplistic.
In fact, I have used the Eigen Library downloaded with Linux, and as both OS are different, that is why there were all of these "errors" displayed.
By downloading this library on Windows, it finally works now.
I thank you for your previous answers, and if someone could answer this last question that Jesper Juhl emitted : why does my program run slowly ? (I use a i5-4690, maybe its existence is the problem) then I would be very thankful.

Thank you in advance,
Sincerely,

Jacataa